# .Net Core Worker Service cannot read service injections

Tags: .net-core

I have created a worker service and hosted in server as a windows services but this
windows service is unable to read service injections.
If i execute the exe directly then this works great. I tried running service from local service account and admin account- cannot find any differences

This is how my Program.cs looks like

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            builder.Build();

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static void ConfigureLog(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            const string loggerTemplate = @"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u4}]<{ThreadId}> [{SourceContext:l}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";
            var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var logfile = Path.Combine(baseDir, "App_Data", "logs", "EmployeePositionsFeed.log");

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.With(new ThreadIdEnricher())
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(logfile, LogEventLevel.Information, loggerTemplate,
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 90)
                .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information("App starting");
        }

        public static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true,
                    reloadOnChange: true);
            return builder.Build();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration configuration = LoadConfiguration();
                    ConfigureLog(configuration);
                    services.AddSingleton(configuration);
                    var winScpSettings = new WinScpSettings();
                    configuration.GetSection("WinScpSettings").Bind(winScpSettings);
                    services.AddSingleton(winScpSettings);
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
```

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly WinScpSettings _winScpSettings;

    public Worker(IConfiguration conf, WinScpSettings wscpSettings)
    {
        _configuration = conf;
        _winScpSettings = wscpSettings;
    }


    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            Log.Information("TransferWorkerService heart beat running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            Log.Information("TransferWorkerService starting at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            Log.Information(_winScpSettings.HostName); //this will come as blank from windows service
            Log.Information(_winScpSettings.SshHostKeyFingerprint);//this will come as blank from windows service

            await new App(_configuration, _winScpSettings).Run();

            Log.Information("TransferWorkerService ended execution at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your appsettings.json file is optional. Try making it required to see if the service fails on startup. Since it is optional you are not going to see a startup exception.

Enter an absolute path for the appsettings.json file and make sure it's there. Choose a directory that is not user-specific but global to the machine (like %programdata% aka C:\ProgramData). If this resolves the issue then you know your issue is the application not being able to find the appsettings.json file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I just tried this option but its not making any difference 

 ConfigureLog();
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile(@"C:\Services\TransferWorkerService\appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                builder.Build();
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return;

Answer (score 0):

I followed

[ASP.Net Core 2.1 application cannot find appsettings.json when ran as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956349/asp-net-core-2-1-application-cannot-find-appsettings-json-when-ran-as-a-windows)

and changed my builder to

```
var processModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
                if (processModule != null)
                {
                    var pathToExe = processModule.FileName;
                    var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
                    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
                }

                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                builder.Build();
```

which fixed my issue.